# Error deploying field with VS Code "Method not implemented"

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I am unable to deploy field changes to my dev org with VS Code, due to the following error when running `SFDX: Deploy source to org`:

> An error was encountered during conflict detection.
> MetadataTransferError: Metadata API request failed: Component
> conversion failed: Method not implemented

- I have pulled the Account object using the CustomObject type in my manifest.
- I am able to deploy Apex Classes just fine
- I can deploy fields using the CLI directly with `sfdx force:source:deploy -m "CustomObject:Account"`

No errors appear in the log file under `~/.sfdx/sfdx.log`

I have verified that my sfdx CLI is up to date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Disable conflict detection during deploy in vscode.

1. Select File > Preferences > Settings (Windows or Linux) or Code > Preferences > Settings (macOS).
2. Deselect (uncheck) `Detect Conflicts At Sync`.
   [image]

Now try deploying the changes. Hope it works.